# I have problem with my game, when the ball goes over the block, it is not deleting from my screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Someone can help me please?

I spent many hours to understand the problem.. (Without success )

I tried to built a 80s hit game.

The problem is that when the ball goes on one of the stones, I catch the event (shows me in the console) and update the list of blocks but the block is not deleted from the screen as if nothing happened and I did not update any list

this is my code:

```
import time
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import random

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

player = Turtle("square")
player.shapesize(1.0, 4.0, 0)
player.color("blue")
player.penup()
player.goto(0, -250)
screen.tracer(0)




blue_turtle = []
blue_positions = []
for i in range(7):
    turtle = Turtle("square")
    turtle.shapesize(2.0 ,4.0, 0)
    turtle.color("blue")
    turtle.penup()
    blue_positions.append((-300 + i * 100, 200))
    blue_turtle.append(turtle)
    
def renderBlocks(b):
    for i in range(len(b) - 1):
        if b[i] == None:
            print("Skipped")
            continue
        else:
            x, y= blue_positions[i]
            b[i].goto(x=x, y=y)
            # total += 100
    
ball = Turtle("circle")
ball.color("white")
    
    
game_on = True
    
def move():
    x = ball.xcor() + 10
    y = ball.ycor()+ 10
    ball.goto(x=x, y=y)

while game_on:
    move()
    
    renderBlocks(blue_turtle)
    for i in range(len(blue_turtle) - 1):
        if (blue_turtle[i] != None) and ball.distance(blue_turtle[i]) < 20:
            blue_turtle[i] = (None)
    
 
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
    screen.update()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: The code you gave is imcomplete, as it missing the imports and definition for the following classes: ball, player & screen

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can actually test the code

Comment: Okay thanks, my bad, i will edit my question now.

Comment: I fixed this, sorry friends i am new here.. 
When the ball goes over one of the blocks the box should be remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
blue_turtle[i] = (None)
```

You tell *your* code that the turtle has been eliminated but you don't tell turtle graphics that it should be removed.  Instead consider:

```
blue_turtle[i].hideturtle()
blue_turtle[i] = None
```

My rework of your code addressing this issue and some others:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def renderBlocks(b):
    for i in range(len(b) - 1):
        if b[i]:
            x, y = blue_positions[i]
            b[i].goto(x, y)

def move():
    if game_on:
        x = ball.xcor() + 10
        y = ball.ycor() + 10
        ball.goto(x, y)

        renderBlocks(blue_turtles)

        for i in range(len(blue_turtles) - 1):
            if blue_turtles[i] and ball.distance(blue_turtles[i]) < 20:
                blue_turtles[i].hideturtle()
                blue_turtles[i] = None

        screen.update()
        screen.ontimer(move, 100)  # milliseconds

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.tracer(0)

player = Turtle('square')
player.shapesize(1, 4, 0)
player.color('blue')
player.penup()
player.sety(-250)

blue_turtles = []
blue_positions = []

for i in range(7):
    turtle = Turtle('square')
    turtle.shapesize(2, 4, 0)
    turtle.color('blue')
    turtle.penup()
    blue_positions.append((-300 + i * 100, 200))
    blue_turtles.append(turtle)

ball = Turtle('circle')
ball.color('white')

game_on = True

move()

screen.exitonclick()
```